# How do I create a shortcut with an associated keyboard shortcut from my .msi

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, keyboard-shortcuts, setup-project

I'm generating a .msi for my program using a Setup project in Visual Studio. This is working fine and creates a desktop shortcut for the program which is great.

Now, I want to be able to run the program using a keyboard shortcut. To do this manually I can right click the shortcut > Properties and change the Keyboard Shortcut property.

However, is there any way I can get my .msi to create the shortcut with the keyboard shortcut already set up?

I've spent some time googling and have found some mentions of the MsiShortcutProperty table but couldn't find anything at all on how to actually use this with my Setup project in Visual Studio.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Setup Projects don't support the HotKey column of the shortcut table.  You might want to try WiX http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/shortcut.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the MsiShortProperty table - you'd need to edit your MSI file (manually with Orca or as a post-build step) to set the Hotkey value for your shortcut:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371847(v=vs.85).aspx

But as Peter R says, if you keep finding needing features that VS setups don't supply then find another tool that does.

Comment: Thanks PhilDW! I edited the msi with Orca as you suggested and then installed my program. When looking at the properties of the shortcut generated, it claimed to have the correct 'HotKey'. However, pressing the HotKey (in my case, F2) didn't launch the program (or do anything at all). But if I remove the hotkey, save and then add it again from the properties menu it works perfectly. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Note that the code I was using in the shortcut table for F2 was 113